# Crystal Reports not showing the PDF files dynamically

Tags: sql, pdf, crystal-reports

Im trying to get dynamic pdf files attached to my Crystal Report. I tried inserting a pdf dummy file using OLE object on crystal reports and going through the following steps:

Format Graphic (of the OLE) --> Picture --> Graphic Location --> Picked the column with the pdf files location and unique names

When I preview the report it still ONLY shows the dummy pdf. Any thoughts?

Thank you very much in advance,

MA

Answer (score 1):

The Dynamic Graphic Location will only be able to work with 'image' file types (Example: .JPG, .BMP and .TIFF) and if a formula is used to dynamically change the image according to a database value, the data will change as expected so the correct image is displayed.

If an image is used the Dynamic Graphic Location will work as expected however if a non-image file type such as .RTF, .PDF are used then this will not work within this formula editor since they are not Graphic files.

If you want to use the Dynamic Graphic Location, your .PDF files would need to be converted to a graphic file such as .JPG, .BMP etc.